# TFS to Mercurial usage change

Tags: tfs, mercurial, migration

I have been using TFS source control until now. Things have changed and I have to work with Mercurial from now on.

Can anyone suggest a good place to start with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best place to start is [HGInit](http://hginit.com/) this is a really good tutorial for Mercurial newbies. Whist it assumes that you've used SVN for centralized version control, TFS and SVN are close enough, as of TFS 2012, that most of the content will be relevant.